Most appropriate circuit simulators for this site?
There are plenty of simulators out there and I'd like to install one. But if I have a question on the main site, I don't want to be using some oddball unreliable simulator because I didn't know any better.  So help a brother out... what's a beginner-friendly simulator that won't make me sorry I installed?

This site has a circuit simulator built in.

When I was a beginner we submitted SPICE jobs in text, adding an arcane JCL wrapper, on Hollerith cards we punched ourselves, and waited for the result to appear on a chain printer. Anything with a GUI looks pretty beginner-friendly to me.

Any one you like.
LTSpice is solid and free. Micro-Cap also.
Fritzing is too simplified for professional work, but if you're just doing power supplies and resistors it's not going to give you a wrong answer. If the cartoonish interface makes it easier for you to understand as a beginner, by all means use it for a while until you learn enough to use the more complicated tools.
